# Более чёткий график на java

Tags: java, графика, java2d

Пишу приложение на `Java` (сторонние библиотеки не предлагайте, пожалуйста), нужно нарисовать график вводимой с клавиатуры функции. 
Пользовался `g.drawPolyLine(xArray[], yArray[], numOfPoints)`, `g` - объект класса `Graphics`, также пробовал `g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2))`, `g2` - объект класса `Graphics2D`, думал, что во втором варианте график будет более чётким, но всё равно получаются одни пиксели, которые резко бросаются в глаза, вот пример:
[image: График]

Если сделать "перо" потолще, результат тот же.
Пробовал посмотреть, как рисуют нормальные графики на сайтах в интернете - там толщина "пера" `2` пиксела, и один из них более светлый, и создаётся иллюзия того, что пикселизацию не видно.
Можно ли добиться такого же результата другим способом или же как реализовать такой же (как на сайтах)?

Попробовал поставить KEY_ANTIALIASING значение VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON (включил антиалисинг), улучшил качество рендера, не особо что изменилось (линия потолще стала и всё, если масштаб увеличить, стало чуть лучше, и всё).

Вот:
[image: После]

Здесь не изменено ничего, кроме настроек рендера. Выглядит немного по-другому, но всё равно не так, как хотелось бы.
Если кто скажет, что лучше сделать нельзя, вот пример:
[image: сайт yotx.ru]
Скриншот с [сайта по построению графиков](http://yotx.ru/#!1/3_h/ubOwf7Owf7Rgzhf23/aH9z52B/52DfiCH8r@3vre/sH@yTaNiNnVPG4@kW43Hr8mJ3f2sfAw==). Хотелось бы получить именно такой результат.

Comment: Если выйдет найти, попробуйте посмотреть алгоритм создания линий в *Paint*. Когда проводишь, линия тоже четкая, как на картинке, а когда отпускаешь — она преобразуется.

Comment: это называется антиалиасинг, попробуйте сделать по инструкциям из официального [руководства](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть настройка рендера, где можно включить антиалайзинг:

```
graphics.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329008/how-to-make-pixel-perfect-line2d-in-graphics2d).

Могу также предложить альтернативу, JavaFX:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LineChartSample extends Application {


    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //Задаем оси
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        //Имя оси
        xAxis.setLabel("Something");
        //Добавляем их на график
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        //Его имя
        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        //Создаем линию графика
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //Втыкаем данные
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));
        //Создаем окно с результатом.
        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Подробнее [тут](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm#CIHGBCFI). Библиотека входит в пакет библиотек jdk.

Comment: Немного не то, что нужно: результат не стал значительно лучше.

Comment: Если использовать Graphic2D, то результат оставляет желать лучшего. Если же использовать просто Graphics, то получается вполне сносный вариант.